# How do you give edit access only to the owner of the sheet in Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have shared a Google spreadsheet with almost 50 people and have linked that sheet with the Google apps script (web app) UI. Now, I would like to give edit access of the sheet only to the owner and make it so that other users can only make any entry through the apps script web app. How can I do this?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I want to restrict the editing in the google spreadsheet, but i don't want to restrict the user if he/she is doing any operation or entry from the front end(apps script-web app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The owner of the sheet needs to publish the WebApp with the following options:

`Execute the app as:` :`Me` and `Who has access to the app`: `Anyone within [you domain]` or `Anyone`

- In this case any user (within your domain) that types the URL of the WebApp into his browser can execute the App without having access to the spreadsheet
- This is because the WebApp will run on behalf of the user who created it - once the user authorized the necessary permissions